# Enable RemoteApp Full Desktop programmatically

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, wmi

I am writing a powershell script to set up some HyperV VM's however there is one step I am having trouble automating. How do I check the box to allow Remote desktop access from the RemoteApp settings programmatically?

[image]

I can set up all of my customizations I need by doing

```
#build the security descriptor so the desktop only shows up for people who should be allowed to see it
$remoteDesktopUsersSid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($remoteDesktopUsersGroup.objectSid[0],0)

#get a copy of the WMI instance
$tsRemoteDesktop = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\CIMV2\TerminalServices -Class Win32_TSRemoteDesktop

#set settings
$tsRemoteDesktop.Name=$ServerDisplayName
$tsRemoteDesktop.SecurityDescriptor= "O:WDG:WDD:ARP(A;CIOI;CCLCSWLORCGR;;;$remoteDesktopUsersSid)"
$tsRemoteDesktop.IconPath = $IconPath
$tsRemoteDesktop.IconIndex = $IconIndex

#push settings back to server
Set-WmiInstance -InputObject $tsRemoteDesktop -PutType UpdateOnly
```

however the instance of that WMI object does not exist until after you have the above box checked.

I attempted to use `Set-WmiInstance` to instantiate and set the settings at the same time but I keep getting errors like:

```
Set-WmiInstance : 
At line:53 char:16
+ Set-WmiInstance <<<<  -Namespace root\CIMV2\TerminalServices -Class Win32_TSRemoteDesktop -Arguments @{Alias='TSRemoteDesktop';Name=$ServerDisplayName;ShowInPortal=$true;SecurityDescriptor=$securityDescriptor}
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-WmiInstance], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetWmiInstance
```

(also after running the command and getting the error it will delete the instance of `Win32_TSRemoteDesktop` if it already exited and un-check the box in the properties setting)

Is there any way to programmatically check that box or can anyone help with why `Set-WmiInstance` throws that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Remote Desktop Services Provider for Windows PowerShell module if you are running windows server 2008 R2.

You can read up about it on technet hear is the [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791871%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

I used this [guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/01/28/managing-remote-desktop-services-aka-terminal-services-using-windows-powershell.aspx) for all my needs .

Comment: Thank you so much, I still need to use `Win32_TSRemoteDesktop` to set things like the `SecurityDescriptor` as they are not available from the `RDS:` provider, but this helps immensely.

Comment: There are two things that I could find that I can't do through the provider, Set the lisening port for the RDP-Tcp connection (currently changing through registry) and setting the advanced settings in `RDS:\RemoteApp\RemoteDesktopAccess` like the Name, SecurityDescriptior, IconPath and IconIndex (currently I need to invoke the WMI object [Win32_TSRemoteDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736367%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and set it through that) Are there any other places I could use or do I need to do the WMI thing.